# HBase Table Design for maintaining hourly visitors count per source

Tags: java, hbase, apache-storm

I am working on a project where I have to report the hourly unique visitors per source. That is I have to calculate unique visitors for each source for each hour. Visitors are identified by a unique id. What should be the design so that calculation of hourly unique visitors is efficient considering the data is of the order of 20k entries per 8 hours.

At present I am using sourceid+
visitorid as the row key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by saying that 2500k entries per hour is a pretty low volume of data (not even 1/second). Unless you want to scale massively your project would be easily achievable with a single SQL server.

Anyway, you have 2 options:

### 1. Non-realtime

Log every visitorid+source and run a job (like mapreduce) to analyze the data every hour, or every day depending on your needs. In this case you can even completely avoid hbase and just stick to hadoop. You can log the data to a different file each hour, process it afterwards and store the results in SQL (or in HBase if you wish). Performance wise this would be the best approach.

### 2. Realtime

Track the data realtime by making use of HBase counters, in this case I'd consider using 2 tables:

- Table *unique_users*: to track the last time a visitorid has visited the site (rowkey would be visitorid+source or just visitorid, depending on if a visitor id can have different sources or just one). This table can have a TTL of 3600 seconds if you want to automatically discard old data as soon as you can but I would let a few days of data.
- Table *date_source_stats*: to track the unique visitorid per source per hour. This table can have a TTL of a few weeks or even years depending on your retention requirements.

When a visitor enters your site you read the *unique_users* table to check the last access date, if that date is older than 1 hour consider it a new visit and increment the counter for the date+hour+sourceid combination in the *date_source_stats* table. Afterwards, update the *unique_users* to set the last visit time to the current time.

That way, you can easily retrieve all the unique visits for a particular date+hour with a scan and get all the sources. You may also consider a *source_date_stats* table in case you want to perform queries for an specific source, i.e, an hourly report for last 7 days for X source... (you can even store all the stats in the same table by using different rowkeys).

> Please notice a few things about this approach:
>
> - I've not being too detailed about the schemas, let me know if you need me to.
> - I would also store total visits in another counter (which would be incremented always regardless of if it's unique or not), it's an
>     useful value.
> - This proposal can be easily extended as much as you want to also track daily, weekly, and even monthly unique visitors, you'll just
>     need more counters and rowkeys: date+sourceid, month+sourceid... In this case you can have multiple column families with distinct TTL properties to adjust the retention policy of each set.
> - This proposal could face hotspotting issues due rowkeys being sequential if you have thousands of reqs per second, you can read more
>     about it [here](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/04/09/hbasewd-avoid-regionserver-hotspotting-despite-writing-records-with-sequential-keys/).
> - An alternative approach for *date_source_stats* could be to opt for a wide design in which you have just a sourceid as rowkey and the date_hour as columns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was facing the problem in implementing the TTL part. I thought I would have to scan my data periodically to delete old entries but with TTL functionality my job would be easier. Can you elaborate on TTL part. Any links where I could learn more about it.

Comment: You can configure your column families in a way their data automatically gets purged on HBase major compactions (scans will stop retrieving the data exactly when they expire). This is an example for 2 column families, one expiring at 1 hour and another one expiring at 1 day: `hbase> create 'table', {NAME => 'family1', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => 3600}, {NAME => 'family2', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => 86400}`, just notice that TTL is applied per column, not per row, when you write to a column that value will last for the TTL defined in its' colfam but other columns of the row will remain for their own TTLs.

Comment: You can easily test the TTLs in the hbase shell: try creating test tables with very low TTLs column families (different for each family), insert some data to them and watch them dissapear magically when they expire. It's a fun practice :) For more info you can take a look at this read: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/admin_writing_data_to_hbase.html

Comment: Thanks for an elaborate answer.